# What is solution to discoloring slate?

Tags: shower, tile

Shower is only months old. Does slate normally bleed like this or did I get bad batch?

[image]

Comment: Looks to be rust, likely from shower head (hopefully)  if not from head then maybe wet behind the tile and rusty nail?

Comment: Your title states, "Discoloring Slate".  It's the grout that's becoming discolored; not the tile.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that one brick has a lot of iron oxide in it which is leaching into the grout and dripping down. Could be an interesting chromatography experiment.

You will need to remove that brick and examine it to determine the problem. It is also slightly possible there is something behind the brick that is rusting, but that is less likely.

Probably you need to replace that brick and then re-grout the stained areas.

Comment: +1, that piece is definitely the culprit. Probably not coincidentally, that stone looks different than the rest.